# how can I append two list with different type?

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8

```
List<ExpenseDetailsWrapper> expenseDataList = reimbursementLocalService
                        .getAllExpenseByReimbursementId(reimbursementId);

                long fileEntryId = 0;
                String previewURL = StringPool.BLANK;
                List<String> billUrlData = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> finalMerge = new ArrayList<String>();
                try { 
                    for (int i = 0; i < expenseDataList.size(); i++) {
                         fileEntryId = expenseDataList.get(i).getFileEntryId();
                         if (fileEntryId > 0) {
                            FileEntry fileEntry = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntry(fileEntryId);
                            previewURL = DLUtil.getPreviewURL(fileEntry, fileEntry.getFileVersion(), themeDisplay, StringPool.BLANK);
                        }           
                         renderRequest.setAttribute("previewUrl", previewURL);
                         finalMerge.add(billUrlData);
                         finalMerge.add(expenseDataList);//**Error is here**The method addAll(Collection<? extends String>) in the type List<String> is not applicable for the arguments (List<ExpenseDetailsWrapper>)
                         LOG.info("File Entries"+fileEntryId);
                    }
                    LOG.info(billUrlData);
                    renderRequest.setAttribute("previewUrl", billUrlData);
                    renderRequest.setAttribute("expenseDataList", expenseDataList);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I have one list with POJO and another one with String.. but when i am trying to add two these list into one it gives me error 
Can i append two list of different type??

Comment: Adding two different types into a generic list is generally bad practice.  The biggest reason: Even if you were allowed to do what you are doing, it would not be _type safe_, because when you go through that list, you don't know if you're getting a string or a details wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with `List<Object> expenseDataList` but while retrieving you need to be careful and cast it.

```
for(Object obj : expenseDataList)
{
  if(obj instanceof YourPOJO)
//take action
}
```

Comment: and we put the reason for downvote on the comment box

Comment: I tried but i think it will not be feasible. Thank you for help